# A particular case of elasticsearch substring query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, substring, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I want to search for a substring in a document column using elasticsearch. The document column contains strings exactly 255 characters long. In that column I want to search occurrences of a substring within a specified position. For e.g. I want to search the substring "ABC" that lies at character position 5-7 of the string. Thus xxxxABCxxxxx... is a valid answer but xxABCxxxxx... is NOT (consider that index starts from 1).

The wildcard query can search substrings but not in a specified fixed position.

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
           "String Name": {
              "value": "*ABC*"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I formulate this query in python?

Comment: Have you tried attempting something python?

Comment: What is that ? Can you elaborate?

Comment: What code you have written in python to achieve this so far?

Comment: I am thinking of padding the query string with '?'s so that it becomes a 255 character string and then running the wildcard query with it

Comment: you have to combine regexp and wildcard query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use the [`regexp`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html) filter to achieve this?

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(...)
resp = es.search(
    index="index-name",
    body={
        "query": {
            "regexp": {
                "String Name": {
                    "value": "^.{4}ABC"
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
print(resp)
```

You'll have to enable [`search.allow_expensive_queries`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html#query-dsl-allow-expensive-queries) to enable usage of the `regexp` filter.

<disclosure: I'm maintainer of the Python Elasticsearch clients and employed by Elastic>